# get 1 string from a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Wel all know that we have to use something like mysql_fetch_assoc to a mysql query to get an associative array and then use $row['foo'] and $row['bar'] to get every value.

Is there a way to optimize the query to get a simple string if we want to return a single column from a single row so that the result will be a simple var and not an associative array?

Thanks.

Comment: For the retrieval of a single value you've described, there seems to be no gain from any optimization, whatever it means. That seems to be the reason why a more straightforward approach is hard to find. Behind the scenes, the same DB mechanisms, drivers, cursors, etc. will be used anyway.

Comment: @full.stack.ex its not hard to find. Dont you know about `mysql_result ` function?

Comment: But it "retrieves the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set." Same result set, just the access method is different. Without profiling, I'm not sure it would save any cycles or bytes. Not any substantial amount, perhaps.

Comment: @full.stack.ex if the result contains only single row and single column calling this function will certainly save cpu cycles for array access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/mysql_result) funciton

```
$res = mysql_query(..);
$str = mysql_result($res, 0, 0);
```

Here `$str` contains the first column of first row.

Also keep in mind that `mysql_result` will move the internal result pointer to point the next row.

Answer (score 1):

Note mysql_ extension is deprecated, you should use mysqli extension or PDO

```
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

list($val) = mysql_fetch_row($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: No.

The long answer: No, but you can optimise the query a little by only returning the row you're looking for (`SELECT my_column...` then `$row['my_column']`). Other than that, you've got to lump it if you use MySQL.